# Spring Boot and ELK

Tags: spring-boot, docker, elastic-stack

I have a series of microservices built using Spring Boot running as docker containers with docker-compose. I want to centralise log files so I'm thinking of using ELK (running in another container). How do I get the log files from the Spring Boot based docker containers to ELK, are they pushed from the containers to ELK or vice versa?

Any example configuration or recent libraries would be much appreciated.

Comment: This would help: https://logz.io/blog/docker-logging/

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. You do not want to parse your log files. Because nobody wants to write regular expressions for parsing and it's error prone.
2. If you have a more dynamic container setup, you do not want to log to files since the setup of all the bind-mounted directories or files is a PITA.

To fix the first problem, add a log appender to log to JSON. I'm using Logback here and you'll need to add `net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder` dependency:

```
<appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH:-.}/your-app-name.json</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>your-app-name.json.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <mdc/>
            <timestamp>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </timestamp>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                    "log.level": "%level",
                    "service.name": "${springAppName:-}",
                    "process.pid": "${PID:-}",
                    "thread": "%thread",
                    "class": "%logger",
                    "mdc": "%mdc",
                    "message": "%message"
                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Then you can collect that file and send it to Elasticsearch; all the fields will be nicely extracted and your multiline log statements (like stacktraces) won't be broken up either:

```
filebeat.inputs:

# Collect the JSON log files from the Spring Boot apps
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/apps/*.json
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["{{ elasticsearch_host }}"]
```

The second problem is a little trickier. I'd use the default JSON log that Docker is providing, so your Java application can simply log to console:

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level %logger{36} [%thread] - %mdc - %msg %n</pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Then Filebeat can automatically collect all the Docker logs (Filebeat will need to have access to `/var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro` for this to work):

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
```

To avoid the parsing issue in the first part, you'd actually need to log JSON to the console and then collect that.

Comment: pretty good points... I honestly believe that using an appender is much better than writing the file to disk and having to configure the filebeats auto-discovery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below architecture,

Spring boot application --> Kafka --> ELK

For this architecture,
1. Configure a Kafka appender on Log4j xml file. Then, logs are automatically pushed to a Kafka topic. 
2. Configure Log-stash configuration as a subscriber on Kafka topic.
3. As well as you can use any filters on Log-stash.

ref : https://www.devglan.com/apache-kafka/stream-log4j-logs-to-kafka

Answer (score 1):

You can send Data from a Source to ELK by using Data Collector.

One such is [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat)

Let's assume you have a Spring-boot Application running on top of Ubuntu Server.

Let's assume you have configured your Application to store log at /home/user/log/ folder.

Now to send this log Data to ELK.

**1. You need to install Filebeat**

```
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-6.6.0-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i filebeat-6.6.0-amd64.deb
```

More detail [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation.html)

**2. Open Filebeat conf and add your log location.**

```
sudo nano /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml


filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true // enable this
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
    - /home/user/log/*.log // add your log path
```

change IP for ELK in Elastic/Logstash and Kibana section in the same file.

**Note:** You can enable output to either Elastic or Logstash so uncomment any one section. 
I would suggest trying the elastic first.

**3. Start Filebeat to send Log.**

**Note:** ELK server should be up and running and accessible from your spring boot server.

To start

```
sudo filebeat -e
```

If all is well you should see filebeat log saying

```
Harvesting Data from your log path.
```

4. Refresh Kibana dashboard and start seeing the log. By default index, created will be `filebeat-*`

Comment: Great thanks for the information, I'll have a go of setting this up. I have one question, I am running my Spring boot applications in docker containers. Should I add filebeat to every container or should I have filebeat as a separate container on every host. I am planning to run [this ELK docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/)  separately for filebeat to send to.

Comment: That depends on the requirement.
If you can collect all spring boot container log at a location using one filebeat.
But in long run, I would suggest having container level filebeat to avoid a single point of failure.

Comment: This is a good starting point, but has two problems: First, the entire log message is just one string and you can't aggregate or filter on log levels or other fields; you'd need to parse the log message. Second, multiline logs like stacktraces will be broken up line by line (which renders them pretty much useless).

Comment: Thanks, @xeraa for pointing out.  Even I faced issue which you mentioned.