# Springboot - Best practises for Monolithic log management

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, elastic-stack

I have a spring boot monolithic application, i wanted to maintain application logs. Right now, i have been maintaining log4j and maintaing a logs in local files. Is it a good approach to maintain them in cloud environment. If so what would be the best option to do so.I have been hearing about ELK, but most of them are suggesting it for micro services applications. Please suggest me what is the best practise to maintain logs.

Comment: show us the effort that you have been doing. The approaches that you took to achieve your objective. In that way, it will be possible for the community to suggest you the correct way. simply asking question without showing your effort is not suggestible.

Answer (score -1):

This is a duplicate question. Please follow the link to get the original post:
[Spring Boot and ELK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520673/spring-boot-and-elk)